# jQuery - How can I do "per element attribute evaluation"

Tags: jquery, debugging, html

I've got a tweaked version of the jQuery [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin.. the only tweaking is the fact that I can set custom attributes instead of global ones.  The reason for this is so that I can have a suffix on some  tags, and no suffix on others.  This tweaking does work perfectly on it's own as I have tested it in different ways.

However, the way I'd like to select the elements/attributes is not working properly.

My markup has the following

```
<time data-suffixAgo="" datetime="2010-06-24T14:10:22Z" title="2010-06-24T14:10:22Z">4 months </time>
<time data-suffixAgo="ago" datetime="2010-11-10T06:00:44Z" title="2010-11-10T06:00:44Z">less than a minute ago</time>
<!-- note the data between the <title> tags is generated server side.
 I'm not talking about that data, just the jQuery information-->
```

And the output at runtime says

```
4 months ago
less than a minute ago
```

now the problem with this is that the "4 months ago" is not supposed to say "ago" because my `data-suffixAgo` attribute is blank

Here is the jQuery I'm using

```
// selects all "time" tags on the page and give the friendly "timeago"
// uses the jquery.timeago.js plugin
// all time tags are created using the "ToTimeSpan" Date Extension Method 
$('time').timeago({strings:{suffixAgo: $(this).attr("data-suffixAgo")}});
```

Can anyone tell my why my selector is not pulling the `data-suffixAgo` attribute on a per element basis?

If I use this

```
    $('time').timeago({strings:{suffixAgo: ""}});
```

the "ago" will be **removed** from all `<time>` tags, and if I do this

```
    $('time').timeago({strings:{suffixAgo: "ago"}});
```

the "ago" will be **added** to all `<time>` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('time').each(function(){
    $(this).timeago({
        strings: {suffixAgo: $(this).attr("data-suffixAgo") }
    });
});
```

The $(this) you have in your code refers to the whole set of $('time').